# How is the theme folder to use decided?

Tags: 7

Under /sites/all/themes there are two folders called atlas and atlas.backup. Drupal 7 is pointing to atlas.backup and I don't understand how Drupal knows which theme folder to use.

I want Drupal to use the *atlas* folder, rather than the *atlas.backup* one.

Comment: I strongly recommend using version control (e.g., git) for backup rather than duplicating files.

Answer (score 3):

You should never, ever keep a duplicate/backup copy of any theme or module anywhere under /sites/all. You can't control which copy Drupal will find first, and you may actually be using parts of both.

You must move the backup copy outside of Drupal root. You will need to clear your caches and perhaps rebuild your registry after you do that.